# Performing boundary value testing on float range

Tags: floating-point, functional-testing, black-box-testing

I want to perform boundary value analysis on a program which takes 3 float variables as input and returns the largest out of them. There's no range specified hence I impose the range to be the one implied by the no. of bytes used to store float variables, in my case 4 bytes. Hence, my float range becomes -3.4+38 to +3.4+38

Problem is: in boundary value u check these points: say your range is : 1<= x <= 10, the points which you need to check are : {1, 2, 9, 10}

In my float example I can't come to understand which value comes just above -3.4+38 and which value falls just below +3.4e+38. someone help here.I don't get this float representation.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that you are programming in C. Any other high-level language should map the concepts to similar notations.

The `float` value just above `-3.4e+38f` is `nextafterf(-3.4e+38f, 0)`. The `float` value just below `3.4e+38f` is `nextafterf(3.4e+38f, 0)`, and you can also compute it as the opposite of the previous one if you find that clearer.

You can also obtain these constants by typing `-3.399999749e+38` and `3.399999749e+38` respectively if you do not have a function `nextafterf`.

---

Note that `3.4e+38f` is not the largest `float`, only a rough approximation of it (and 3.4+38, or approximately 41.4, even less so).